# Text keeps going over image everytime I resize, no matter what I do it keeps overlapping the Logo

Tags: html, css

Have done some researching on why it is doing this but, I can't seem too fix the problem. The header logo/text keeps overlapping. Anyone got an idea why it is doing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/uljima/bcm96v49/

resized:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2P3z.png

Tried many things but it keeps on overlapping the logo.

HTML:

```
<html>
<header>
<title>KeyStone Coffee</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</style>
</head>
<div class="wrapper">
<body>
    <body>
        <header>

            <div class= "Company_Logo">
                <a href="http://imgur.com/Qu8f4K3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Qu8f4K3.png" title="source: imgur.com"  alt="Company Logo" height="200" width="200"/></a>
            </div>

            <center>
            <div class= "Company_Text">
            <h1>Keystone Coffee</h1>
            </div>
            </center>

            <div class="HPFGAC">
            <nav>
            <ul>
            <center>
                <li><a href = "index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href = "Products/Products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">FLAVORED COFFEE</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">GUIDE TO THE PERFECT TASTE</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </center>
            </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>
    </html>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
height: 850px;
width: 960px;
margin:0 auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;

}

.row:after{
clear: both;
}
.col{
background: black;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
padding: .5px;
float: left;
margin: 1%;
width: 100%;
}
.row:after{
clear: both;
}

.col{
background: black;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
padding: .5px;
float: left;
margin: 1%;
width: 100%;
}
.WebContainer{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.articles{
width:90%;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
} 

.DIV
{
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
}
.box2 {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
margin: 1em;
}
html{
overflow: scroll;
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
width:100%;
}
body {
height: 960px;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
header {
background: white;
color: Black;
padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
float: center-side;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
header h1 {
margin: 0px;
display: inline;
float: center-side;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
nav ul{
margin: 0px;
padding : 0 0 15px 0;
display: inline;
float: center-side;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
nav ul li{
background: wwhite;
color: #9D795B;
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 5% 15px 20px 15px;
margin: 0;
float: center-side;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
font-size: 1.875em;
white-space:nowrap;
}
nav ul li a {
color: #9D795B;
float: center-side;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.Company_Logo{
float:center-left
clear: both; 
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
right: 70.5%;
z-index: 9999;
display: block;
white-space:nowrap;
padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
.Company_Logo{
width:100px;
}
.Company_Text{
clear: both; 
color:#9D795B;
font-size:50.5px;
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
display: inline;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.Company_Text{
clear: both;
position: relative;
top: 35px;
right: -2.75%;
z-index: 9999;
}

.HPFGAC{
clear: both;
font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
white-space:nowrap;

}
.HPFGAC a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}

.HPFGAC a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.HPFGAC a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

   .HPFGAC a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

nice try but i must say you need some real work on your codes, it is pretty messed up.

HTML

```
    <title>KeyStone Coffee</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</style>
</head>
<div class="wrapper">

    <body>

        <body>
            <header>
                <div class="Company_Logo"> <a href="http://imgur.com/Qu8f4K3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Qu8f4K3.png" title="source: imgur.com"  alt="Company Logo" height="200" width="200"/></a>

                </div>
                <center>
                    <div class="Company_Text">
                            <h1>Keystone Coffee</h1>

                    </div>
                </center>
                <div class="HPFGAC">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <center>
                                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href="Products/Products.html">PRODUCTS</a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">FLAVORED COFFEE</a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">GUIDE TO THE PERFECT TASTE</a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>

                                </li>
                            </center>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
 #wrapper {
     height: 850px;
     width: 960px;
     margin:0 auto;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center center;
 }
 .row:after {
     clear: both;
 }
 .col {
     background: black;
     border-radius: 5px;
     color: white;
     padding: .5px;
     float: left;
     margin: 1%;
     width: 100%;
 }
 .row:after {
     clear: both;
 }
 .col {
     background: black;
     border-radius: 5px;
     color: white;
     padding: .5px;
     float: left;
     margin: 1%;
     width: 100%;
 }
 .WebContainer {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
 }
 .articles {
     width:90%;
     height: auto;
     margin: auto;
 }
 .DIV {
     margin-left:0px;
     margin-right:0px;
 }
 .box2 {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
     margin: 1em;
 }
 html {
     overflow: scroll;
     height: 100%;
     margin: auto;
     width:100%;
 }
 body {
     height: 960px;
     margin: 0;
     padding:0;
     width:100%;
     text-align:center;
 }
 header {
     background: white;
     color: Black;
     padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
     float: center-side;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }
 header h1 {
     margin: 0px;
     display: inline;
     float: center-side;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }
 nav ul {
     margin: 0px;
     padding : 0 0 15px 0;
     display: inline;
     float: center-side;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }
 nav ul li {
     background: wwhite;
     color: #9D795B;
     display: inline-block;
     list-style-type: none;
     padding: 5% 15px 20px 15px;
     margin: 0;
     float: center-side;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     font-size: 1.875em;
     white-space:nowrap;
 }
 nav ul li a {
     color: #9D795B;
     float: center-side;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }
 .Company_Logo {
     float: left;
     padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
 }
header center{
    overflow: hidden;
}
 .Company_Text {
     padding-top: 30px;
     color:#9D795B;
    text-align: left;
     font-size:50.5px;
     font-family:'Lobster', cursive;
     white-space:nowrap;
 }
 .HPFGAC {
     clear: both;
     font-family:'Anton', sans-serif;
     white-space:nowrap;
 }
 .HPFGAC a:link {
     text-decoration: none;
 }
 .HPFGAC a:visited {
     text-decoration: none;
 }
 .HPFGAC a:hover {
     text-decoration: underline;
 }
 .HPFGAC a:active {
     text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

Link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sabipu/bcm96v49/2/)

i hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: it works but how do I center both of them they seemed to be on the left side.

Comment: hey there, sorry coulndt get you with your answer quick, here is your answer. http://jsfiddle.net/sabipu/bcm96v49/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
.Company_Text {
 clear: both;
 color:#9D795B;
 font-size:50.5px;
 font-family:'Lobster', cursive;
 display: inline;
position: relative;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
.Company_Text {
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 top: 30px;
margin-left: 210px;
 right: -2.75%;
 z-index: 9999;
}
.HPFGAC {
 clear: both;
 font-family:'Anton', sans-serif;
 white-space:nowrap;
margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Try this.